# SQL Error while restoring big database in Mysql

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump

I have successfully created a MYSQL dump on RHEL 6 machine. The dump file is having 40 GB.

When I try to restore it in an UBUNTU machine I got this error.

[image]

Comment: How the backup was taken ?

Comment: mysqldump -u myuname -p mydb > path/to/mydbdump.sql